# Write texture mapped obj file to disk with VTK

Tags: opengl, vtk, texture-mapping, 3d-rendering

I am using VTK to read an obj file, texture map the 3D model and transform it to another view (by applying rotateY/X/Z transforms to vtkActors) and writing it to file using vtkwindowtoImageFilter. Due to this pipeline, the rendered image is displayed on the screen before being written to file. Is there a way to do the same pipeline without the image being displayed on screen ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VTK 5.10 or earlier, you can [reander the geometry off screen](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/OffScreenRendering).

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for. I am new to vtk and I found the above link looking for a way to convert a triangular surface to volume data, ie, to voxelize the surface. All profile I found on the internet is about using vtkwindowtoImageFilter to obtain a 2D section of the screen, have you worked out a way to access 3D data of the rendered window? Please tell me about that.